# ЧПУ с несколькими ГЕТ

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Приветствую, поделитесь опытом. Как можно организовать ЧПУ вот для такой ссылки:
/index.php?action=search&name=ip=&server=&q=44&mod=all&location=all
Как видно это поиск, и иногда идет пустой запрос.

Comment: добавили ещё пару ссылок, может и понятнее стало бы. А пока я вижу такое

    /all_search/all/44

расшифровка

    /$mod$_search/$location$/$q$

если я правильно понял, что mod - это от слова модуль или mode (режим).

Остальные параметры мне не сильно понятны.

Comment: согласен, а как быть если там не all и не 44 а пустая строка.
В итоге /all_search////44/all/all

Comment: нужно смотреть, какие есть варианты. Может быть и дефолтный вариант придумается.
А может просто составить список вариантов, и просто исключать пустые.

    /all_search////44/all/all

превращается в 

    /all_search/44/all/all

главное, что бы ссылки были уникальные